# Vue js always run a function to see if user is online or offline

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hi to all i want to find a way to see if user in my webapp is online or offline and run always! If user is offline wait 10 seconds to see if come back online and if not run a function!

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Maybe a `watch` could be used on `$nuxt.isOffline`  https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/$nuxt/ or simply using vanilla JS could probably also work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/Online_and_offline_events

Answer (score 3):

Create a component `OfflineComponent.vue` like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>Offline component after 5 seconds!</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showOnce: false,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.startInterval()
  },

  methods: {
    startInterval() {
      window.setInterval(() => {
        if (this.$nuxt.isOffline && !this.showOnce) {
          this.runThisFunc()
          this.showOnce = true
        }

        if (this.showOnce) {
          clearInterval(window)
        }
      }, 5000)
    },

    runThisFunc() {
      console.log('OFFLINE!')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Now import it inside the page you want. I use the main page:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="$nuxt.isOffline">
    <offline-component></offline-component>
  </div>
  <div v-else>You are Online!</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import OfflineComponent from '~/components/offlineComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
  components: {
    OfflineComponent,
  },
}
</script>
```